# Border color in Hyperref with Asymptote

Tags: hyperref, asymptote

`Hyperref` usually puts a colored border around the links. However, if I insert the `Asymptote` package, that *border disappears* (even if the link remains). Looking at the Asymptote [manual](https://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/ctan/graphics/asymptote/doc/asymptote.pdf) (page 172) it seems to me that through the variable `hyperrefOptions` it is possible to change this behavior, but I don't understand exactly how to proceed from a practical point of view. I state that I am not an expert on the Asymptote package, but the documentation seems a bit cryptic to me. So, how can I exactly modify my code/settings in order to make the box visible (as in the figure)?

[image]

Here is my minimal code:

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{hyperref}
    \hypersetup{allbordercolors=blue}
\usepackage{asymptote}

\begin{document}

Hello\footnote{Hello again}

\begin{asy}[width=6cm,height=6cm]
import three;
surface cube1 = scale3(1.6)*shift((-0.5,-0.5,-0.5))*unitcube;
draw(cube1,red);
\end{asy}

\end{document}
```

Comment: you can probably convince asymptote not to do this, but easier is probably simply `\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 1}` after \begin{document}.

Comment: Have you tried moving `\usepackage{hyperref}` and your `\hypersetup` to after all the other imports? The hyperref manual explicitly says, "Make sure it comes *last* of your loaded packages [emphasis in original]."

Comment: @UlrikeFischer In fact with `\hypersetup{pdfborder=0 0 1}` it works! It was immediate but for some reason it will have escaped me. That's the right answer. Thanks so much.


@CharlesStaats Yes, I have seen this clarification, but I have left it that way because this example has been taken from my other code which loaded other packages. In that case it only worked if I put it after `hyperref`. Anyway thanks you too